DynamoDB concurrency
I have an AWS Lambda function that is invoked concurrently N times and I have to trigger an action once it is invoked for the N-th time.
The documentation about DynamoDB atomicity/transactionality is a bit confused: link.
My current solution (python SDK boto3) is to combine counters and ConditionExpressions:
# Lambda content...
try:
    dynamo_table.update_item(
        Key={ 'Id' : id },
        UpdateExpression="ADD file_processing_count :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':inc': -1, ':min': 1},
        ConditionExpression='file_processing_count > :min',
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
    all_file_processed=False
except:
    all_file_processed=True


Is this sufficient to prevent race conditions?

All singleton operations in DynamoDB are strongly serialised and atomic, as all writes are handled by a leader node. For that reason you'll never encounter a race condition, all updates will be applied in the order received by DynamoDB.

Ok, thank you. Do you agree that this is the only way to achieve the purpose in the question?
If I try to decrement the counter and retrieve the value in two separate operations, then I would be exposed to the race condition do you agree?

(With race condition I mean that the lambda is invoked N times but the final action is triggered 0 times or more than one).

It sounds like you're asking about idempotency, where you want to make sure each update happens only once. You can use transactions for that, or Lambda Power tools can also provide idempotent guarantees.

It seems that is not possible to write and read in the same transaction. Can you kindly provide an example?

You cannot, you can only do one or the other.

Ok thank you, so what is the proper way to decrement a variable and check if it is 0? Is the proposed solution (in the question) acceptable?

Yes, your condition would ensure that you cannot add to the count if the counter is 1 or less.
